# Hibernate property configuration in Spring applicationContext.class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a running spring application with applicationContext as @Configuration annotated class. It has a mysql datasource configured using hibernate and spring data-jpa.

I need to drop the existing database and create a new database based on my domain model everytime I run the application.

I know I have to set

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

But how do I set this property in my java configuration class?

Please suggest.

Thanking You.

Comment: Show us your full XML configuration that contains that `property`. Is it a `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set up your `SessionFactory`. If you are using a [`LocalSessionFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html), it has a `hibernateProperties` field of type `Properties`, with a corresponding getter and setter.

Just create a `Properties` object, add the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property with the value you wanted, and use the setter to pass it.